# Group data by users on Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group data from one column by data in another column, but I only want data from a specific time range. So let's sat 2015-11-1 to 2016-4-30. My database looks something like this:

```
  account_id    employer_key    login_date
  1111111       google          2016-03-03 20:58:36.000000
  2222222       walmart         2015-11-18 11:52:56.000000
  2222222       walmart         2015-11-18 11:53:14.000000
  1111111       walmart         2016-04-06 23:29:04.000000
  3333333       walmart         2015-09-05 14:13:53.000000
  3333333       walmart         2016-01-28 03:20:58.000000
  2222222       walmart         2015-09-03 00:11:38.000000
  1111111       walmart         2015-09-03 00:12:25.000000
  1111111      dell_inc         2015-11-13 01:59:59.000000
```

I am trying to get an output that looks something like this:

```
  account_id             login_date
  1111111                3
  2222222                2
  3333333                1
```

How can I go about getting the unique sums from the account_id's for a certain time window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first filter your DF and then use `.groupby().count()`:

```
In [213]: df.query("'2015-11-01' <= login_date <= '2016-04-30'") \
            .groupby('account_id')['login_date'] \
            .count() \
            .reset_index()
Out[213]:
   account_id  login_date
0     1111111           3
1     2222222           2
2     3333333           1
```

Alternatively you can use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (`df.loc[...]`) instead of `df.query(...)`, but it will look bit bulky...

Answer (score 1):

Using `between` and `value_counts`

```
v = pd.value_counts(df.account_id[df.login_date.between('2015-11-01', '2016-04-30')])
v.rename_axis('account_id').reset_index(name='login_date')

   account_id  login_date
0     1111111           3
1     2222222           2
2     3333333           1
```